# Checking if string contains only strings from a table

Tags: vba

I need to check if my Listbox.List(i) string contains only numbers and signs '-','x' and '/'.

I tried to do it in opposite way

```
arrS= Array("a lot of signs")
For Each El in arrS
    If Instr(Listbox.List(i),El)>0 Then
          badSignFound = True:Exit For
    End If
```

But this is non efficient. I have tried to do some counter, but still with INSTR i dont get only boolean 1 or 0, but position.

Is there any way i can just do a table from sings i need (1,2,3,4,5,'x','/','-') and do some checking of my string? Or i have to do this huge table and do it in my way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, something like:

```
Function validate(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "[^0-9/\-x]"
    validate = Not re.test(s)
End Function
```

This will return `True` if the string is in the alphabet `0123456789-/x` and otherwise `False`.

See [this](https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/) for more on regular expressions in VBA.